# Determine if QTableView has an open editor

Tags: qt, qtableview

Is there any way to determine if a `QTableView` has an open editor in the current cell? I need to handle the following situation:

- A user double-clicks a cell and edits the data, but *leaves the cell in the "edit" state*.
- On another part of the UI, an action is taken that changes the selected row of the underlying model.
- Back on my view, I want to determine if the newly selected row is the same as the open row. If not, I need to take an action. (Prompt the user? Commit automatically? Revert?)

I see how to get the current item, and can get the delegate on that item, but I don't see any `isEditMode()` property I was hoping to find.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass your delegate so that it includes an accessor that tells you when it's editing:

```
void MyDelegate::setEditorData ( QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex & index ) const {
    // _isEditing  will have to be mutable because this method is const
    _isEditing = true; 
    QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
}

void MyDelegate::setModelData ( QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index ) const {
    QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor, model, index);
    _isEditing = false;
}

bool MyDelegate::isEditing() const { return _isEditing; }
```

Then you can just check the delegate to see what's going on.  Alternatively and/or if you don't like the `mutable`, you can emit signals so you know what state the delegate is in.

Comment: Just a note, I think you meant *mutable*, not *volatile*.

Comment: @Caleb - You're right. Changed -- and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As already pointed out by Florian Kusche in his answer, this doesn't work because setModelData() is only called if the editing is committed, but not if it's canceled.

Answer (score 10):

Just check whether the return value of

```
State QAbstractItemView::state () const
```

is

```
QTableView::EditingState
```

Comment: I am not sure that if its on that state is enough to determine that it is for the **current cell**

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass `QTableView` in order to be able to access the `state()` function, which is unfortunately protected. However, I did not try that.

If you already have an `QStyledItemDelegate` subclass, you can use it to track whether an editor is currently open. However, you can't just use `setEditorData`/`setModelData`, because `setModelData` won't be called, when the user cancels editing. Instead, you can track the creation and destruction of the editor itself.

```
class MyItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyItemDelegate( QObject* parent = nullptr );
    ~MyItemDelegate();

    QWidget* createEditor( QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const;
    void setEditorData( QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index ) const;
    void setModelData( QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index ) const;

    bool isEditorOpen() const   { return *m_editorCount > 0; }

protected:
    int* m_editorCount;

protected slots:
    void onEditorDestroyed( QObject* obj );
};
```

Implementation:

```
MyItemDelegate::MyItemDelegate( QObject* parent ) :
    QStyledItemDelegate( parent )
{
    m_editorCount = new int;
    *m_editorCount = 0;
}

MyItemDelegate::~MyItemDelegate()
{
    delete m_editorCount;
}

QWidget* MyItemDelegate::createEditor( QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    // create an editor, can be changed as needed
    QWidget* editor = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor( parent, option, index );

    connect( editor, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), SLOT(onEditorDestroyed(QObject*)));
    printf( "editor %p created\n", (void*) editor );
    (*m_editorCount)++;

    return editor;
}

void MyItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    ...
}

void MyItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    ...
}

void MyItemDelegate::onEditorDestroyed( QObject* obj )
{
    printf( "editor %p destroyed\n", (void*) obj );
    (*m_editorCount)--;
}
```

On some occasions, e.g. when moving to the next item in the tree using the cursor keys, Qt will create the new editor first and then destroy the old one. Hence, `m_editorCount` must be an integer instead of a bool.

Unfortunately, `createEditor()` is a `const` function. Therefore, you cannot create an `int`-member. Instead, create a pointer to an `int` and use that.

Comment: Nice. Just a few comments: better use mutable int instead of int*. Also, no need to reimplement setEditorData() and setModelData() in your provided solution, so you could have omitted them for clarity.

Comment: Yes you're right. Mutable ints would be a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

Connect to underlying model dataChanged signal

```
void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged ( const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight )
```

You can check if the cell where data has changed is the same than the currentIndex

```
QModelIndex QAbstractItemView::currentIndex () const
```

You cannot know if the current cell had an open editor straight, but can check if the view is in QAbstractItemView::EditingState

```
State QAbstractItemView::state () const
```

It should be enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of the item being edited, you can call `indexWidget()` and attempt to cast it. If it's valid, you not only know you're editing, but you also have your editor widget handy.

```
EditWidget *editWidget = qobject_cast<EditWidget*>(tableView->indexWidget(tableView->currentIndex()));
if(editWidget)
{
    //yep, ur editing bro
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, its even helpful to get the edit/combo widget before the edit begins...

just emit a signal and consume it in the mainwindow... this is what I used one to get combo box in QTableWidget before editing...

first create a signal in ComoBoxItemDelegate...

```
signals:
   void OnComboEdit(QComboBox* pCombo) const;
```

then emit the signal in the createEditor method...

```
QWidget* ComboBoxItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    // Create the combobox and populate it
    QComboBox* cb = new QComboBox(parent);
    emit OnComboEdit(cb);
    return cb;
}
```

and in the MainWindow declare a function to receive the singal...

```
void MainWindow::OnComboEidt(QComboBox *pCB) const
{
    qDebug() << "Combo Eidt Singal Received";
}
```

Then finally in the constructor of MainWindow connect it...

```
ComboBoxItemDelegate* cbid = new ComboBoxItemDelegate(ui->tableWidget);
connect(cbid, &ComboBoxItemDelegate::OnComboEdit, this, &MainWindow::OnComboEidt);
ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, cbid);
```